# AngularJS getter / setter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setter, getter

I'm learning angular and I'm trying to figure out what is the best solution to use getters/setter.

Saying, I'm using a library which exposes getters and setters (as Moment.js does).

I've tried several ways to deal with getters and setters, here they are:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Example - example-ngModel-getter-setter-production</title>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="getterSetterExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="userForm">
      Name :
      <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="user.name" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
      <br/>Name1:
      <input type="text" name="userName1" ng-model="user1.name" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
      <br/>Name2:
      <input type="text" name="userName2" ng-model="user2.name" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
      <br/>Name3:
      <input type="text" name="userName3" ng-model="user3.name" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
    </form>
    <pre>user.name =         <span ng-bind="user.name()"></span>
      </pre>
    <pre>user1.name =        <span ng-bind="user1.name()"></span>
      </pre>
    <pre>user2.name =        <span ng-bind="user2.name()"></span>
      </pre>
    <pre>user3.name =        <span ng-bind="user3.name()"></span>
      </pre>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
  angular.module('getterSetterExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        var _name = 'Brian';
        var _name3 = 'Joe';


        var name1 = {
          _name: 'George',
          name:function(newName) {
            if (angular.isDefined(newName)) {
              this._name = newName;
            }
            return this._name;
          }
        };

        var name2 = {
          _name: 'Michael',
          name:function(newName) {
            if (angular.isDefined(newName)) {
              this._name = newName;
            }
            return this._name;
          }
        };

        var name3 = {
          name:function(newName) {
            if (angular.isDefined(newName)) {
              _name3 = newName;
            }
            return _name3;
          }
        };

        $scope.user = {
          name: function(newName) {
            if (angular.isDefined(newName)) {
              _name = newName;
            }
            return _name;
          }
        };

        $scope.user1 = {
          name: name1.name
        };

        $scope.user2 = {
          name: function(newName) {
            return name2.name(newName);
          }
        };

        $scope.user3 = {
          name: name3.name
        };

      }
    ]);
```

You can try it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/S1qKre9umNpLOt0sjpZf?p=preview

2 Questions:

user1 tries to direcly use the getter/setter provided by the name1 objet, it doesn't work properly, can you explain why?

Is there a way to avoid to rewrite a "proxy" for each getter/setter as I've done in user3? what would be the best method to use getters/setters provided by an external library?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> user1 tries to direcly use the getter/setter provided by the name1 objet, it doesn't work properly, can you explain why?

The issue is with the context, You are just merely copying the function reference `name1.name` by doing:-

```
    $scope.user1 = {
      name: name1.name
    };
```

so when it is run `this` in the getter will actually point to the `window`/global (in non strict mode). You can workaround this by using [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Example:-

```
    $scope.user1 = {
      name: name1.name.bind(name1)
    };
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SjO7Oe?p=preview)**

> Is there a way to avoid to rewrite a "proxy" for each getter/setter as I've done in user3?

I would just create a wrapper so that i don't run into context issues like these.

```
    $scope.user = getModel('name', 'Brian');

    $scope.user1 = getModel('name', 'George');

    $scope.user2 = getModel('name', 'Michael');

    $scope.user3 = getModel('name', 'Joe');

    $scope.address = getModel('address');


  //You can improve this by passing an optional getter functionality as well for some specific evaluation on the value when set.
  function getModel(propertyName, defValue) {
      var obj =  {};

      obj._defVal = defValue;
      obj[propertyName] = function(newVal){
        if (angular.isDefined(newVal)) {
          obj[prop] = newVal;
        }
        return obj[prop];
      }

      return obj;
    }
   }
```

Or just

```
 function getModel(propertyName, defValue) {
      var obj =  {};
       var propValue = defValue;
      obj[propertyName] = function(newVal){
        if (angular.isDefined(newVal)) {
          propValue = newVal;
        }
        return propValue;
      }
      return obj;
    }
  }
```

**[Demo2](http://plnkr.co/edit/y0AhYc?p=preview)**

Comment: I've a concern regarding the scope.You pointed that the mistake was the wrong scope during execution.I've tried to modify the code to include name2 into the scope like this: I replaced var name2 by $scope.name2 and modified index.html ng-model="name2.name". I was expecting to fix the scope issue by having this binded to the scope. Where is the mistake?

Comment: "You pointed that the mistake was the wrong scope during execution" Not really i meant wrong context pointed by _`this`_. I did not get what you mean. Can you paste your code in a plunker..

Comment: I've edited the code here http://plnkr.co/edit/3dh1DmGvIy6V7YPPEfKV?p=preview (8th version) -- look at line 20 in index.html and line 18 in app.js. I expected this to be binded to $scope at execution time.

Comment: @ChrisDunom Not really.. See the line from angular code `if (ctrl.$options && ctrl.$options.getterSetter && isFunction(modelValue)) {
      modelValue = modelValue();
    }` Bascially the function reference is `modelValue` and it is just executed with no context. It is just the copy of function reference that is being executed. This is always the problem when we use `this` in the piece of code where we dont have a control over the execution context.